# Converting a cell array into an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a: 1×7 cell array of strings:

```
arr1 = '0.1' '0.4' '0.0' '0.1' '0.4' '0.0' '2.1'
```

I need to transform this thing into a proper matrix 1x7 matrix. If I do:

```
cell2mat(arr1)
```

I get:

```
'0.10.40.00.10.40.02.1'
```

It gives me a single string. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str2double`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html):

```
>> arr1 = {'0.1' '0.4' '0.0' '0.1' '0.4' '0.0' '2.1'};
>> result = str2double(arr1)
result =
    0.1000    0.4000         0    0.1000    0.4000         0    2.1000
```

---

Why didn't your approach work? Because `cell2mat` simply concatenates the contents of the cells, which are strings, so you get a single string instead of several numbers.

Comment: @Andry Prego! :-)